# About an orthogonal complement theorem

Tags: vector-spaces

> Let $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, there will one **unique** vector $y \in W$ that fulfils:
>
> $$(x-y) \perp w \ \ : \ \ \forall w \in W$$

I have trouble understanding this. Look:

---

Let $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$$W = \{ (0,0) , (2,2) \}$$

Which is a valid subspace, right? Now, according to the theorem, for any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, there will be one unique vector $y \in W$ that

$$(x-y) \perp w \ \ : \ \ \forall w \in W$$

So, let's pick

$$x = (5,5)$$

There are two candidates for $y$. Let's start working with

$$y = (0,0)$$

Observe that

$$((5,5) - (0,0)) \perp w \ \ : \ \ \forall w \in W$$

Is false because clearly

$$(5,5) \cdot (2,2) = 20 \not = 0$$

So let's pick the other candidate:

$$y = (2,2)$$

Observe that

$$((5,5) - (2,2)) \perp w \ \ : \ \ \forall w \in W$$

Is false too, because

$$(3,3) \cdot (2,2) = 12 \not = 0$$

---

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You are wrong when you say that $W$ is a subspace because it is not closed under scalar multiplication

Comment: The vector space $W$ is more than two points; it is _all_ points spanned by those two vectors (I am assuming that is what you meant, at least).

Comment: @JulianP: You're right! I guess that's the problem?